How to prove $a ≤ b$ OR $b ≤ a$ for all $a, b$ in $\mathbb{N}$?
I'm currently reading Terence Tao's "Analysis I" and I'm at the beginning where he defines the natural numbers and proves some of their basic properties using the Peano axioms.
I've nearly finished the whole section, but this is something I would like to prove. I don't know if mathematical induction should be used.
Definition.
For natural numbers $m$ and $n$, $m ≤ n$ if and only if there exists an $x$ in $\mathbb{N}$ such that $m + x = n$.
My attempt. A proof by induction. Let $P(a, b)$ be true for $a, b$ in $\mathbb{N}$ if and only if $a≤b$ OR $b≤a$. By showing that $P(0,b)$ is true for all $b$ in $\mathbb{N}$ and $P(k,b) \implies P(k+1,b)$ for all $b$ in $\mathbb{N}$, the statement is proved.
Base case: $a = 0$. $0 ≤ b$ is true for all $b$ in $\mathbb{N}$ from a proof I have already completed.
Induction step: showing $P(k,b) \implies P(k+1,b)$. Suppose for the induction that $k≤b$ OR $b≤k$. Then $k+1≤b$ OR $b≤k+1$ because...
And that's where I don't know what to do. I don't know how to obtain $k+1≤b$ OR $b≤k+1$ from the induction hypothesis. Thanks for reading and any responses.

For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., here, here, here and here.

I do not think that induction is suitable here. You can use that one of $a-b\le 0$ and $a-b\ge 0$ must be satisfied (this even works for real numbers). From this , your claim follows immediately.

When you're trying to prove very basic things like this about natural numbers, you must specify your starting point. Do you have a definition of $\leq$? What axioms are you working with?

With $a$ fixed, prove by induction on $b$; then use Generalization on $a$.

What is generalisation? @Mauro

If it holds for a whatever, it holds for every a.

Separate the cases:
If $b \leq k$, then $b \leq k + 1$ should be easy to show.
If $k \leq b$, you can further distinguish the cases $k < b$ and $k = b$. In the former, you'd want to show that $k < b$ implies $k + 1 \leq b$. Depending on what exactly you already have proven about $+1$, $<$ and $\leq$, this might need some work. If $k = b$, then $b \leq k + 1$ is again easy.

Thank you very much! @Arno
